# How to add an empty array using when and otherwise in pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

How can i add an empty array when using `df.withColomn` `when()` and `otherwise(***empty_array***)`
New column type is `T.ArrayType(T.StringType())` from UDF

I want to avoid ending up with NaN values.

Comment: maybe`lit([])`?

Comment: Already tried that but get an error: `Unsupported literal type class java.util.Arraylist []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `array(lit(None))`

```
df.select(when(col('target_bool')=='true',array(lit(1))).otherwise(array(lit(None)))).show()
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `F.array([])` and `F.array(F.lit(none))` ?

Comment: Using `lit` for literals is recommended. Both are correct otherwise

Answer (score 0):

**Try below - Create a column with None value and cast to Array()**

```
df_b = df_b.withColumn("empty_array", F.when(F.col("rn") == F.lit("1"), (None))).withColumn("empty_array", F.col("empty_array").cast(T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
df_b.show()



 root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rn: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- case_condition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- empty_array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```